# Finding average in column

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to know why this code isn't working, the error I get is Run-time error '6' Overflow. The code will do the average for the 1st itteration then stops. I will attach a picture of how the excel spread sheet. What im trying to do is E: ((D)/(C*B))*100, and the for loop is there to itterate the next average column whihc is K.

[image]

```
Sub avgeer()    
    Dim LastAvgRow As Double
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet '<-- O1 Filteration in my code
    Dim lngPasteOffsetCol As Double
    Dim itter As Double    

    Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("O1 Filteration")

    lngPasteOffsetCol = 0    

    LastAvgRow = wsTarget.Cells(wsTarget.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For lngPasteOffsetCol = 0 To 54
        If lngPasteOffsetCol = 0 Then
            lngPasteOffsetCol = lngPasteOffsetCol    
        Else
            lngPasteOffsetCol = lngPasteOffsetCol + 5    
        End If

        For itter = 0 To LastAvgRow - 1    
            'LastAvgRow = wsTarget.Cells(wsTarget.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row    
            Range("E1").Offset(itter, lngPasteOffsetCol).Value = (Range("C1").Offset(itter, lngPasteOffsetCol).Value) * Range("B1").Offset(itter, lngPasteOffsetCol).Value    
            Range("E1").Offset(itter, lngPasteOffsetCol).Value = Range("D1").Offset(itter, lngPasteOffsetCol).Value / Range("E1").Offset(itter, lngPasteOffsetCol).Value        
        Next itter    
    Next lngPasteOffsetCol    
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you doing this in a loop. It appears you need a basic formula. `=(D1 / (C1*B1)) * 100` - just use that and drag it down for each row.

Comment: Or this...`Range("E1").Offset(itter, lngPasteOffsetCol).FormulaR1C1 = "=(D" & itter & " / (C" & itter & "*B" & " & itter & ")) * 100"`

Comment: You would have gotten the overflow when `itter` was `LastAvgRow` due to `0 / 0` giving an overflow.  Are you still getting it now that you fixed that?  Do you have any rows where either column B or C, and column D, are zero?

Comment: @MichaelZ. Or even `Range("E1:E" & LastAvgRow).Formula = "=D1/(C1*B1)*100"` so that you can avoid the loop or the manual drag.  ;)

Comment: hey guys If i did it that way wont it only do column E, what about column K and so on? and the other thing Im confused on is how do I update my lastAvgRow variable so that I know which is the last used row? I updated the code with the for loop I just realised I missed it.

Comment: Yes, so would have to use another formula for the other column. You don’t need offset. You’re just adding complexity to something simple.